# Reading from user_input causes ":|" to appear in output

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

My code is using [`read_line_to_codes/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_codes/2) and [`read_stream_to_codes/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_stream_to_codes/2) in order to read from `user_input`. This is how these reads are organized:

```
main :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, [A]),
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, B),
    /* Some parsing happens here */
    read_stream_to_codes(user_input, C),
    /* Some more parsing happens here and the code goes on */
```

I am compiling the program using the following command:

```
swipl -q -t main -o program -c program.pl
```

The program runs fine, however due to those reads in main, I get an output with the `|:|:` characters (the swipl console shows `|:` whenever the user has to input something). When I remove all I/O code from the program, it runs without outputting those characters.

Is there any way to get rid of this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`prompt1/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prompt1/1) predicate to set the prompt for the next line or [`prompt/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prompt/2) to change to prompt message globally.

E.g. using `prompt1/1`:

```
?- read_line_to_codes(user_input, L).
|: test
L = [116, 101, 115, 116].

?- prompt1(''), read_line_to_codes(user_input, L).
test
L = [116, 101, 115, 116].
```

or, using `prompt/2`:

```
?- prompt(Old, 'Give me: ').
Old = '|: '.

?- read_line_to_codes(user_input, L).
Give me: abc
L = [97, 98, 99].
```